# Changing a single table from DirectQuery to Import

Tags: powerbi

I have a table that I pulled for a report using DirectQuery.  I find myself needing to change that table (and only that table) to Import mode so I can merge in a table (entered using the "Enter Data" option).  Is there a way to change only a single table to Import?  I looked online, and all the answers I saw said to right-click on the table, and select the "properties" option to change the storage mode, but the properties option isn't listed.  I'm at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can alter the storage mode from Direct Query to Import for selected objects. The table properties are in the relationship designer (in the most recent version of Power BI, I think the documents haven't been updated on the MS Docs site), there you can change it to 'Import'. Warning you can't change Import to Direct Query, so always save a version before you do it just in case you need to go back

[image]

Comment: What's the "relationship designer "?